# When does a $p$-group split as semidirect product with its commutator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Given a (finite) group $G$ and its commutator subgroup $G'$, when is it the case that
$$1\to G'\to G\to G/G'\to 1$$
splits?

Specifically, can we say anything if we add the assumption that $G'$ is abelian ($G$ is nilpotent of class 2), or more generally if $G$ is nilpotent?

**EDIT** It is most interesting to consider this question when $G$ is a $p$-group. We may furthermore simplify this by supposing that $G$ is a $p$-group of exponent $p$ (ie. $g^p=1$ for every $g\in G$), and therefore both $G'$ and $G/G'$ are both elementary abelian.

Comment: It never splits when $G$ is nilpotent (provided that $G' \ne 1$).

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is nilpotent and $G' \ne 1$, then $G'$ does not have a complement in $G$.

Because if it had a complement $Q$, say, then $Q \cong G/G'$ would be abelian, so $$G' = [QG',QG'] = [Q,Q][Q,G'][G',G'] = [Q,G'][G',G'] \le [G,G'].$$

But if $G$ is nilpotent with $G' \ne 1$ then $[G,G']$ is the next term in the lower central series of $G$, so it is strictly contained in $G'$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The *Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem* states that if 
$G$ is a finite group, and 
$N$ is a normal subgroup whose order is coprime to the order of the quotient group 
$G/N$, then the short exact sequence
$$
1\to N\to G\to G/N\to 1
$$ 
splits. In particular, this applies for the normal subgroup $N=G'$, if the orders are coprime.

If $N$ is abelian, we can use the second group cohomology $H^2(G/N,N)$. If it is trivial, then the extension splits.

Comment: I don't see why this applies to the commutator subgroup (the quaternion group $\mathbb H$ has commutator $\{-1,1\}$ equal to the center). Also I unfortunately don't know anything about group extensions, do you think you could give an elementary explanation?

Comment: "I don't see why this applies to the commutator subgroup":  The commutator group certainly is a normal subgroup, so you can apply Schur-Zassenhaus for situations where the orders are coprime. Also, Schur-Zassenhaus has a fairly elementary proof.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this to mean for all commutator subgroups. Unfortunately, this is not very helpful for nilpotent groups, since the most basic form of nilpotent group is a $p$-group, in which case the commutator subgroup and its quotient will never be coprime (unless in the trivial case) as I intended to point out is the case with the quaternion group.

Comment: Yes, this is true. For this reason nilpotent groups are "exciting"; their cohomology is non-trivial, and their extensions are interesting.

Comment: The more I think about this the more I feel I may not be asking the right question. I just realized that the quaternion group would give a direct counterexample if I was hoping for the sequence to split over _every_ nil-2 group. Do you know of anything that can be said about this question if we only consider $p$-groups?